# Structures and Strings of Characters

Tags: c, string, character, structure

Basically, I have an issue understanding the question.

So I'm trying to stimulate a number of elevators.

- Initially, all elevators are at the 1st floor with 0 passenger inside
  and 0 usage (i.e., no one has finished using them yet).
- Given a sequence of floor numbers, an elevator goes to the
  corresponding floors one by one.
- If an elevator goes from a lower floor to a higher floor m, m
  passengers will attempt to enter the elevator. However, once the
  number of passengers in the elevator reaches 15, which is the
  capacity of the elevator, no additional passengers will be able to
  enter the elevator.
- If an elevator with p passengers goes from a higher floor to a lower 
  floor n, n (or p, whichever is smaller) passengers will exit the
  elevator. The actual number of passengers who exit the elevator
  should be counted towards the number of passengers who have finished 
  using the elevator.

And thereafter, I'm trying to print out the corresponding floor, number of passengers and usage.

```
Enter number of elevators: 1 
Enter sequence for elevator 1: 24653    
Elevator 1: 
Floor: 3 
Number of passengers: 4 
Usage: 8 
Most used elevator: 1

Enter number of elevators: 2
Enter sequence for elevator 1: 24653
Enter sequence for elevator 2: 798635
Elevator 1:
Floor: 3
Number of passengers: 4
Usage: 8
Elevator 2:
Floor: 5
Number of passengers: 5
Usage: 15
Most used elevator: 2
```

I need assistance with my functions "runElevators" and "goToFloor" as I'm not sure what is required in them. I think I did something wrong in "runElevators", but I'm not sure what exactly.

I understand that character "2" does not imply integer "2" but I can't seem to work around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CAPACITY 15
#define MAX_LEN 21
#define MAX_ELEVATORS 5

typedef struct { 
    int floor, passenger, usage;
} elevator_t;

void setupElevators(elevator_t [], int);
void readSequences(char [][MAX_LEN], int);
void runElevators(elevator_t [], char [][MAX_LEN], int);
void goToFloor(elevator_t *, int);
void printElevators(elevator_t [], int size);
int mostUsedElevator(elevator_t [], int);

// This function is given. You are NOT to modify it.
int main(void){
    int size;
    elevator_t elevators[MAX_ELEVATORS];
    char sequences[MAX_ELEVATORS][MAX_LEN];

    printf("Enter number of elevators: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    setupElevators(elevators, size);
    readSequences(sequences, size);

    runElevators(elevators, sequences, size);

    printElevators(elevators, size);
    printf("Most used elevator: %d\n", mostUsedElevator(elevators, size));

    return 0;
}

void setupElevators(elevator_t elevators[], int size){

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        elevators[i].floor = 1;
        elevators[i].passenger = 0;
        elevators[i].usage = 0;
    }
}   

// Read in the sequences of floors the elevators go to.
// This function is given. You are NOT to modify it.
void readSequences(char sequences[][MAX_LEN], int size){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<size; i++){
        printf("Enter sequence for elevator %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", sequences[i]);
    }
}

void runElevators(elevator_t elevators[], char sequences[][MAX_LEN], int size){


    int i, c;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for(c = 0; c < strlen(sequences[i]); c++)
        {   
            elevators[i].floor = sequences[i][strlen(sequences[i]) - 1];

            if((elevators[i].passenger < 15) && (sequences[i][c+1] > sequences[i][c]))  
                elevators[i].passenger += sequences[i][c];

            if(elevators[i].passenger > 15)
                elevators[i].passenger = 15;

            if((elevators[i].passenger > 0) && (sequences[i][c] > sequences[i][c+1]))
                elevators[i].passenger -= sequences[i][c+1];

            if(sequences[i][c] > sequences[i][c+1])
                elevators[i].usage += sequences[i][c+1];
        }

}


void goToFloor(elevator_t *elevator, int floor){




}   
void printElevators(elevator_t elevators[], int size){

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        printf("Elevator : %d\n", i+1); 
        printf("Floor: %d\n", elevators[i].floor);
        printf("Number of passengers: %d\n", elevators[i].passenger) ;
        printf("Usage: %d\n", elevators[i].usage);
    }
}

int mostUsedElevator(elevator_t elevators[], int size){
    // Incomplete
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem specifically, I don't understand what is going on. Explain what you expect and what actually happens. Also, `for(c = 0; c < strlen(sequences[i]); c++)` is very bad because `strlen()` computes the length each time, something like `while (sequence[i][length++] != '\0')`. So `for(c = 0 ; sequences[i][c] != '\0' ; c++)` is a lot better.

Comment: "I think I did something wrong". Can you please elaborate on that? Describe the input, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
void runElevators(elevator_t elevators[], char sequences[][MAX_LEN], int size)
{
    int i, c;
    int prevFloor, currFloor;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < strlen(sequences[i]); c++)
        {   
            prevFloor = elevators[i].floor;
            currFloor = sequences[i][c] - '0';

            if (currFloor > prevFloor)
            {
                // Elevator going UP, passengers will enter the elevator
                int numPassengerToEnter;

                // Max capacity of elevator is CAPACITY (=15)
                numPassengerToEnter = CAPACITY - elevators[i].passenger;

                // At floor m, only m passengers (= currFloor) are available (to enter elevator)
                if (numPassengerToEnter < currFloor)
                {
                    elevators[i].passenger += numPassengerToEnter;
                }
                else
                {
                    elevators[i].passenger += currFloor;
                }
            }
            else if (currFloor < prevFloor)
            {
                // Elevator going DOWN, passengers will exit the elevator
                int numPassengerToExit;

                // Smaller of (Current floor number n) and (current number of passenger in elevator) will exit the elevator
                if (elevators[i].passenger < currFloor)
                {
                    numPassengerToExit = elevators[i].passenger;
                }
                else
                {
                    numPassengerToExit = currFloor;
                }

                elevators[i].passenger -= numPassengerToExit;
            }

            // Update current floor of elevator
            elevator[i].floor = currFloor;
        }
}
```